# Suppress Build Output When Running `dotnet run`

Tags: c#, .net, build

Is it possible to suppress the build warnings which are output when `dotnet run` causes a build to occur, e.g. after a code change?

```
$ dotnet run --verbosity quiet

/../MyProgram.cs(6,21): warning CS8618: Non-nullable property
    'MyProperty' must contain a non-null value when exiting
    constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

<My Program Output>
```

This is painful, as during development I will pipe my program output into another tool, and the build warning output breaks the parsing of that tool. I don't want to disable any particular warnings; I want to simply omit them from the output of `dotnet run`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ dotnet run --property WarningLevel=0
```

- `--property:<NAME>=<VALUE>` to pass properties to MSBuild
  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run)
- `WarningLevel=[0,1,2,3,4]` to configure the level of warnings to be output where `4` is the default and `0` disables all warnings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings)

Answer (score 2):

I have found that you need multiple switches for this to work more reliably:

`dotnet build --nologo -v q --property WarningLevel=0 /clp:ErrorsOnly`

where:

- `--nologo` suppresses the header
- `-v q` sets output verbosity to quiet
- `--property WarningLevel=0` is for MsBuild, and described well in other answers.
- `/clp:ErrorsOnly` means **C**onsole**L**ogger**P**arameters

For reasons, I have not fully explored, `dotnet run` does not always respect these arguments, so I stitch these together with bash/pwsh:

```
dotnet build --nologo -v q --property WarningLevel=0 /clp:ErrorsOnly && dotnet run --no-build
```

Disclaimer: disabling warnings is a generally a bad idea